# How to save root aliases permanently?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, mac, bash

i tried saving aliases (see below) for the root user in `.bash_profile` to /var/root/.bash_profile and restarting Terminal, but it didn't work. where does the `.bash_profile` file need to be to maintain persistent aliases in the terminal?

```
$ cat /var/root/.bash_profile
alias grep='grep --color=always'
alias net='sudo netstat -ap tcp && sudo lsof -Pn -i4'
```

my specifications:

```
sh-3.2# system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: OS X 10.8.5 (12F45)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 12.5.0
      Boot Volume: lily
      Boot Mode: Normal
      Computer Name: lily’s MacBook Air
      User Name: System Administrator (root)
      Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
      Time since boot: 12:37
```

Comment: hmm, nope, that didn't work. but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: that didnt work either. should there be a `.bashrc` in the `/var/root/` directory? i just noticed theres no bashrc

Comment: thanks. sourcing the file definitely works, but its not persistent. when i quit Terminal completely and restart it, then `$ sudo su` to get root, the aliases arent available anymore

Comment: thanks! using `.profile` (not .bash_profile) with `$ sudo -i` works! if you put it in an answer ill gladly accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper config file name of the standard root shell (i.e. sh) is .profile. So change the name of .bash_profile to .profile:

```
mv /var/root/.bash_profile /var/root/.profile
source /var/root/.profile
```

This is working logging in as root in the GUI.

---

Trying to `sudo su` in a sudoer's shell won't fetch root's .profile file. Use `sudo -i` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo ln -s "/Users/${LOGNAME}/.bash_profile" /var/root/.profile`

Result:

```
$ sudo ls -lha /var/root/.profile
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    24B Oct  5 12:40 /var/root/.profile -> /Users/phx/.bash_profile
```

Then your own `~/.bash_profile` will load for root when you `sudo -s` or `sudo -i` *(along with your functions and aliases)*.

I have not been able to get this to work for one-off `sudo` commands, however.

Comment: Needless to say this has some risks if your normal account has a low-quality password.

Comment: I wrote this answer, and as a security researcher I can say that it's also unsafe. `~/.bash_profile` is a user-writeable location, and anything in it gets automatically executed as root during a root-level shell session, so it could actually be used to establish persistence.  Granted you would have to know that `/var/root/profile` was symlinked to `~/.bash_profile`, but it's still not secure. Just saying.